# Problem with if-else conditions in Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, bots

Hey guys I have a problem with the if-else conditions.I was creating the following bot that searches and alerts me when theres a appointment available but I can't make the if-else conditons work at the final lines of the code,the bot doesn't respect the if-else conditions I've tried changing several times the code but no idea of how to resolve this problem.Thanks for the help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep
import time
import re
import os
import winsound

duration = 2000  # milliseconds
freq = 900  # Hz

lets_go = True

while lets_go == True:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.implicitly_wait(30) 
    browser.maximize_window()  
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    browser.get("https://icp.administracionelectronica.gob.es/icpplus/index.html")
    browser.verificationErrors = [] 
    
    
    cookie_kill = browser.find_element_by_id("cookie_action_close_header")
    cookie_kill.click()
    #sleep(1)
    madrid = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form"]/option[34]')
    madrid.click()
    #sleep(1)
    accept = browser.find_element_by_id("btnAceptar")
    accept.click()
    #sleep(1)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    tramites_group = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div/div/section/div[2]/form[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/fieldset/div[2]/select/option[3]')
    tramites_group.click()
    sleep(1)
    
    aceptar = browser.find_element_by_id("btnAceptar")
    aceptar.click()
    sleep(1)
   
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    enter_button = browser.find_element_by_id('btnEntrar')
    enter_button.click()
    sleep(1)
    
    passport = browser.find_element_by_id("rdbTipoDocPas")
    passport.click()
    passport_number = browser.find_element_by_id("txtIdCitado").send_keys("123456789")
    person_name = browser.find_element_by_id("txtDesCitado").send_keys("BORIS JOHNSON")
    person_birth = browser.find_element_by_id("txtAnnoCitado").send_keys("1900")
    nationality = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div/div/section/div[2]/form/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div/div/span/select/option[200]')
    nationality.click() 
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")    
    sleep(1)
    
    enviar = browser.find_element_by_id("btnEnviar")
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", enviar)
    sleep(1)
    
    enviar = browser.find_element_by_id("btnEnviar")
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", enviar)
    sleep(1)
    
    no_appointments = browser.page_source.find("En este momento no hay citas disponibles.")
    
    if no_appointments:
       browser.close()
       time.sleep(120)
       
    else:
         winsound.Beep(freq, duration)
         print("found")
         lets_go = False
         break
```

Answer (score 1):

`page_source` returns a normal Python string.  The `find` method of a string does not return a boolean True/False.  It returns the starting character number if found, and -1 if not found.  Thus, you want:

```
    no_appointments = browser.page_source.find("En este momento no hay citas disponibles.")
    
    if no_appointments >= 0:
       browser.close()
       time.sleep(120)
```

You might consider whether it makes more sense to write:

```
    if "En este momento no hay citas disponibles" in browser.page_source:
```